# Jquery filter function STILL not respoding to pseudo-selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

REPOST--there were mistakes in my original post that got many answers sidetracked... resolved the mistakes but still not working!--

So I have a jquery keyup/filter function filtering a large table, to simulate a 'search' feature by keyword. It's all one table with headers and topic rows included. I'm trying to get the function to ignore topic rows, which are in a class 'hideTopic,' which I attempted to exclude with the `:not()` pseudo-selector. At the moment, if someone searches the wrong keyword, it's returning every single topic row (see picture below).

```js
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#searchable tr:not(.hideTopic)").filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<input id="myInput" type="text" />
<table id="searchable" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <td><br><br><br>
      <p class="header" id="PVInsuranceVerification">Insurance Verification</p>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </thead>
  <thead>
    <tr class="hideTopic">
      <th scope="col">Topic</th>
      <th scope="col">PDF</th>
      <th scope="col">Video</th>
      <th scope="col">HealthStream</th>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Adding/Updating Insurance<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td>
      <td class="center"><a href="training/Provider_to_Patient_Contact/Adding-Updating-Terminating_Insurance.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td>
      <td class="center">
        <a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=d1e03099-c094-4100-8001-ecc0c7f994b1" target="_blank">
          <!--UPDATE-->Video</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6NTA6NDQmY2lkPWE0M2UwYjAwLTc1ZjktZTgxMS1hNjIxLTAwNTA1NmIxNTIyYiZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Batch Eligibility<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td>
      <td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Batch_Eligibility.pdf">PDF</a></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eligibility<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td>
      <td class="center"><a href="training/Provider_to_Patient_Contact/Eligibility_-_Single_Patient_at_Time_of_Service.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td>
      <td class="center">
        <a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=b957bb26-2814-495f-94ef-5cbdf1efc886" target="_blank">
          <!--UPDATE-->Video</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6NTE6MzkmY2lkPTA2MTFjZjY0LWNhZjgtZTgxMS1iZjI5LTAwNTA1NmIxN2M4MCZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>eCW Eligibility Verification<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td class="center">
        <a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=7291fc54-00b2-4279-a36f-f203834d4b91" target="_blank">
          <!--UPDATE-->Video</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>eCW Eligibility Verification (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="center">
        <a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=65f2b0db-0013-41ad-a9bf-5169bb7678d0" target="_blank">
          <!--UPDATE-->Video</a>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eligibility - Single Patient at Time of Service<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td>
      <td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Eligibility_-_Single_Patient_at_Time_of_Service.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td>
      <td class="center">
        <a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=129f71df-b17b-4c65-b6ff-6b2aa8a9971f129f71df-b17b-4c65-b6ff-6b2aa8a9971f" target="_blank">
          <!--UPDATE-->Video</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6NTE6MzkmY2lkPTA2MTFjZjY0LWNhZjgtZTgxMS1iZjI5LTAwNTA1NmIxN2M4MCZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eligibility Verification Common Mistakes and Best Practices<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td>
      <td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/MM_PROJECT_Eligibility_Overview_ILT_v2CE.pptx">PPTX</a></td>
      <td class="center">
        <a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=efee1c3d-b9b8-4a2a-beb0-dea3494cce68" target="_blank">
          <!--UPDATE-->Video</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eligibility Verification Common Mistakes and Best Practices (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td>
      <td class="center"><a href="training/11e/11e_Eligibility_Verification_Common_Mistakes_and_Best_Practices.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td>
      <td class="center">
        <a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=65f2b0db-0013-41ad-a9bf-5169bb7678d0" target="_blank">
          <!--UPDATE-->Video</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>How to Submit eSAF for Passport OneSource Access<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td>
      <td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/eSAF_for_Passport_OneSource_How_to_JA.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Insurance Requested Process<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td>
      <td class="center"><a href="training/Provider_to_Patient_Contact/Insurance_Requested_Process.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td>
      <td class="center">
        <a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=9f4ffd55-cc80-4bff-8465-cc8d67a3b840" target="_blank">
          <!--UPDATE-->Video</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6NTI6NTQmY2lkPTkzOTJmMGViLWQwZjgtZTgxMS1iYjYwLTAwNTA1NmIxNjgwYyZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Insurance Requested Process (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td>
      <td class="center"><a href="training/11e/11e_Insurance_Requested_Process.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td>
      <td class="center">
        <a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=2ebf0296-70d7-48b5-8639-cd3ba3349ec8" target="_blank">
          <!--UPDATE-->Video</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Interpreting Passport Verifications<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td class="center">
        <a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=eacf514c-5712-4356-95f1-a77610d570c8" target="_blank">
          <!--UPDATE-->Video</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Iplan Selection<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td class="center">
        <a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=c75bb339-0377-4430-9181-04f9cc52b984" target="_blank">
          <!--UPDATE-->Video</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MVA Case Management What You Need to Know<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td class="center">
        <a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=4f76de39-6f82-4fa0-a597-af068b5dfaf8" target="_blank">
          <!--UPDATE-->Video</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MVA Case Management Process<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td class="center">
        <a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=bb83be0e-8b5d-455d-9587-e8b1196e47b1" target="_blank">
          <!--UPDATE-->Video</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Payer Website Request Form<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td>
      <td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Payor_Access_Request.pdf">PDF</a></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <thead>
      <td><br><br><br>
        <p class="header" id="ptDemoEntry">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</p>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><a href="#topPage" style="color:#1e345d;">^Back to Top</a></td>
    </thead>
    <thead>
      <tr class="hideTopic">
        <th scope="col">Topic</th>
        <th scope="col" ">Docs</th>
                            <th scope="col " >Videos</th>
                            <th scope="col " >HealthStream</th>
                          <td class="center "></td></tr>
                        </thead>
                      <tr><td>Adolescent Portal Consent Documentation<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Adolescent_Portal_Consent_Documentation.pdf
          " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a></a></td></tr> 
                      <tr><td>Demographic Entry Standard<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Demographic_Entry_Standards.pdf " target="_blank
          ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=145b5a74-5af2-4e49-bde4-9044c884c34a " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6MzU6MjAmY2lkPWI2NzM2ZGE2LTlhZmMtZTgxMS1iOTI5LTAwNTA1NmIxMzBlZiZjdj0w
          " target="_blank ">Course</a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Demographic Entry Standards (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/11e/11e_Demographic_Entry_Standards.pdf " target="_blank
          ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=2828d566-f5fa-482c-83d2-864e33633b2b " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Duplicate Account Process<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/FOS_Duplicate_Account_Process.pdf " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center
          "><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=8562444e-91c7-49c3-bbf9-43c24e50edba " target="_blank ">Video</a></td><td class="center "><a href=" " target="_blank "></a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Duplicate Account Process (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/11e_Duplicate_Account_Process.pdf " target="_blank
          ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=3f5e4ddc-5959-48b0-9c63-d5e964a1c46d " target="_blank ">Video</a></td><td class="center "><a href=" " target="_blank "></a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Duplicate Account Process FAQ<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Duplicate_Account_Process_FAQs.pdf " target="_blank
          ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href=" " target="_blank "></a></td><td class="center "><a href=" " target="_blank "></a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Entering Email Addresses<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Entering_Email_Address.pdf " target="_blank
          ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=b5a890a3-9f91-42ed-84d6-7b9be425fc4b " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6NDU6MTgmY2lkPWQ3Y2ExNjRjLTZiZjktZTgxMS1hNmMzLTAwNTA1NmIxNDFjYyZjdj0w
          " target="_blank ">Course</a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Entering Email Addresses (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/11e/11e_Entering_Email_Address.pdf " target="_blank
          ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=a126a73c-f026-4e28-bb68-678e7ef68ea8 " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Entering Patient Demographics<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Entering_Patient_Demographics.pdf " target="_blank
          ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=9932eb38-2890-480f-8a29-e2a6812cfe33 " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6Mzk6MjImY2lkPTI1YTRiNTc5LTc4ZjktZTgxMS1iMzQxLTAwNTA1NmIxNDU2YSZjdj0w
          " target="_blank ">Course</a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Entering Patient Demographics (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/11e/11e_Entering_Patient_Demographics.pdf " target="_blank
          ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "></td><td class="center "></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Entering Out of Office Visits (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/11e/11e_Entering_Out_of_Office_Visits.pdf " target="_blank
          ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=0c5d51e0-7566-4b5d-a169-d0c006195233 " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Patient Demographic Log<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Patient_Demographic_Log.pdf " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>SOGI<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/SOGI.pdf " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=b013b257-1f83-4c7c-9bd6-e1d3106f7fdb
          " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6NDY6NTYmY2lkPWY3NTFiZjAwLTc0ZjktZTgxMS1iOTA1LTAwNTA1NmIxMGUzMyZjdj0w
          " target="_blank ">Course</a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>SOGI (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/11e/11e_SOGI.pdf " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=b110d072-9632-4a4b-b14e-36c5d33ca826
          " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Adding, Updating, Terminating Insurance<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/FOS_Adding_Updating_Terminating_Insurance_DH_10.20.20.pdf
          " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=aeb6ad6d-6783-4c07-a1ab-e0c893e0084c " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6NTA6NDQmY2lkPWE0M2UwYjAwLTc1ZjktZTgxMS1hNjIxLTAwNTA1NmIxNTIyYiZjdj0w
          " target="_blank ">Course</a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Adding, Updating, Terminating Insurance (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/11e_Adding-Updating-Terminating_Insurance.pdf
          " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=98f7c963-8d79-48e4-aa92-3981ce8b2f00 " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Adolescent Portal Consent Documentation<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Adolescent_Portal_Consent_Documentation.pdf
          " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a></a></td></tr> 
                      <tr><td>Validation - Check In<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Check_In.pdf " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center
          "><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=8edd6899-4132-415b-b84c-2ec2d6fd73df " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTU6MTI6MDEmY2lkPWIxZDdlYTNkLWM5ZjgtZTgxMS04N2FlLTAwNTA1NmIxN2UzNCZjdj0w
          " target="_blank ">Course</a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Check In (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/11e/11e_Check_In_done.pdf " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center
          "><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=af496e2b-91da-483d-a915-a952cb25f1ba " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Completing the Medicare Secondary Payor (MSP) Form<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/1006a-MEDICARE STATUS QUESTIONNAIRE
          ATTACHMENT A.docx " target="_blank ">Doc</a></td><td class="center "><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=248de31e-9d05-4784-87c7-19a85e60d6c7 " target="_blank "><!--UPDATED-->Video</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDQtMjNUMTU6MDg6MjMmY2lkPTJkMjFjYzQ0LWNiODktZTcxMS1hYjk4LTAwNTA1NmIxMmI5YyZjdj0w
          " target="_blank ">Course</a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Completing the Medicare Secondary Payor (MSP) Form (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "></td><td class="center "><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=8c8babb8-5515-4b2a-98b8-482533fd2f2a
          " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Patient Registration Form - Spanish<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Patient_Registration_Form_eCW_2011_Spanish.pdf
          " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "></td><td class="center "></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Patient Registration Form (eCW)<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Patient_Registration_Form_eCW_2011.pdf
          " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "></td><td class="center "></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Percent Copays<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Percent_CoPays.pdf " target="_blank
          ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=d889a5ed-f7be-4da1-a726-23b6082f76d4 " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTU6MTQ6MTImY2lkPWE2OGU4NDJlLWQ0ZjgtZTgxMS1hYjc2LTAwNTA1NmIxMzcyMSZjdj0w
          " target="_blank ">Course</a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Percent CoPays (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/11e/11e_Percent_CoPays.pdf " target="_blank
          ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=1f509134-2f99-4e0d-812d-976c6bdd9fc1 " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Telephone Consent<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Telephone_Consent.pdf " target="_blank
          ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=f2a9f253-6f3a-4044-8859-c18b44f67106 " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTU6MTU6MDYmY2lkPTA1NWEyM2U2LTE2MDMtZTkxMS05MmMwLTAwNTA1NmIxN2UzNCZjdj0w
          " target="_blank ">Course</a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Telephone Encounters (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/11e/11E_Telephone Encounters.pdf " target="_blank
          ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=3feb4d81-083f-4fb0-9706-17afe0d90acb " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Troubleshooting - Insurance Eligibility<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Troubleshooting_–_Insurance_Eligibility.pdf
          " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "></td><td class="center "><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTU6MTY6MTAmY2lkPTQ3NmVhZTc1LTI2ZmUtZTgxMS1iNjUyLTAwNTA1NmIxMDY1NyZjdj0w
          " target="_blank ">Course</a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Adding I-Plans for Self Pay Inpatients/ER Patients<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Adding_iPlans_for_Self_Pay_In-Patient_ER_Patients.pdf
          " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=80dcff0a-e36d-48e5-b5cb-328802c7c67d " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTgtMTItMTlUMjE6NTA6NTMmY2lkPWU4NzM1OGEzLWNlZjgtZTgxMS1iOTA1LTAwNTA1NmIxMGUzMyZjdj0w
          " target="_blank ">Course</a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Adding I-Plans for Self Pay Inpatients/ER Patients (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/11e/11e_Adding_iPlans_for_Self_Pay_In-Patient_ER
          Patients.pdf " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=759c91b9-ea7d-45c4-958a-0e8604dbcf37 " target="_blank ">Video</a></td><td class="center "></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Alerts: Billing, Global, Insurance, Meaningful Use<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Alerts-Billing,_Global,_Insurance,_Meaningful_Use.pdf
          " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=7b733853-7840-473f-ac13-ee8136f9b09a " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTgtMTItMTlUMjE6NTE6MjAmY2lkPTRkZjg4YmEzLTcwZjktZTgxMS1iMzc5LTAwNTA1NmIxMGYwMiZjdj0w
          " target="_blank ">Course</a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Alerts: Billing, Global, Insurance, and Meaningful Use (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/11e/11e_Alerts – Billing_Global_Insurance_and_Meaningful_Use_done.pdf
          " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "></td><td class="center "></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Appointment Right Chart Panel<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Appointment_Right_Chart_Panel.pdf " target="_blank
          ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=cbbb8f74-18e2-415e-b8ec-68bc2d08e443 " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTgtMTItMTlUMjE6NTI6MzAmY2lkPTVhMGI2MjUwLWEyZmMtZTgxMS1hODFlLTAwNTA1NmIxNDk2MSZjdj0w
          " target="_blank ">Course</a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Appointment Right Chart Panel (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/11e/11e_Appointment_Right_Chart_Panel_done.pdf
          " target="_blank ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=306c9561-1a6f-4ab1-a55c-15b0d0897efe " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE--></a></td><td class="center "></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Validation - Terminating a Patient<span style="display:none; ">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center "><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Terminating_a_Patient.pdf " target="_blank
          ">PDF</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=024a9eb4-4d23-40bd-876d-e67abd7297bb " target="_blank "><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center "><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTgtMTItMTlUMjE6NTI6NTEmY2lkPTI0ZjI2NzAyLWI4ZjktZTgxMS1iYjYwLTAwNTA1NmIxNjgwYyZjdj0w
          " target="_blank ">Course</a></td></tr>
                      
    </html>
```

Comment: You seem to have `thead` as a child of `tbody` - not sure that's valid HTML, but change your selector to `$("#searchable > tbody > tr:not(.hideTopic)")`

Comment: Easiest way to test seems to be to change `$(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)` to `$(this).toggle(false)` - then you'll know if it's your selector or your .text check

Comment: agree to freedom, a thead after a tr element seems awkward to me

Comment: Aside the strange table structure that was pointed out and which is not a problem for the jQuery lookout in question... Your snippet seems to be working. Those two rows (*Topic - PDF - Video - HealthStream*) are not toggled in any case. So could you please clarify what is the expected behavior?